# Borel measurability is a local property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking at Exercise 5.2 (page 44) in "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" by Richard Bass.

> Let $f:(0, 1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for every $x\in (0, 1)$,
>   there exist $r>0$ and a Borel measurable function $g$, both depending
>   on $x$, such that $f$ and $g$ agree on $(x-r, x+r)\cap (0, 1)$. Prove
>   that $f$ is Borel measurable.

**Attempt.** For each $x\in (0, 1)$, let's denote $r_{x}$ and $g_{x}$ to be the quantities given in the problem statement. By choosing $r_x$ sufficiently small, we may assume that $(x-r_{x}, x+r_{x})\subseteq (0, 1)$. Then for $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
f^{-1}((a, \infty))=\{y: f(y)>a\}=\bigcup_{x\in (0, 1)} \{y: g_{x}(y)>a\}\cap (x-r_{x}, x+r_{x})
$$
Since $g_{x}$ is Borel measurable, we know that $\{y: g_{x}(y)>a\}\cap (x-r_{x}, x+r_{x})$ is a Borel set. But the union above is uncountable; so how do we show that $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is a Borel set?

**Attempt 2.** Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $(0, 1)$, we can try looking at the points $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (0, 1)$. But then the intervals $(x-r_{x}, x+r_{x})$ need not cover $(0, 1)$. The standard example is as follows. Suppose $\{q_1, q_2, …\}$ is enumeration of rationals in $(0, 1)$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. If we let $r_{q_{j}}$ to be $\varepsilon 2^{-j}$, then the measure of $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (q_j-r_{q_{j}}, q_{j}+r_{q_{j}})$ is at most $2\varepsilon$.

**Attempt 3.** If each $g_{x}$ is continuous, we would be done. In that case, $$\{y: g_{x}(y)>a\}\cap (x-r_{x}, x+r_{x})$$ would be an open set; so as a union of open sets, $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ would be an open set, and hence Borel.

Comment: Every open cover in $\Bbb{R}$ has a countable subcover!

Comment: You can take $x$ being rationals

Comment: @PhoemueX: How do we know $\{y: g_{x}(y)>a\}$ is an open set? We only know it is a Borel set.

Comment: @Ilya: If you could elaborate, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: For every $x \in (0,1)$ there is some $r_x > 0$ such that on $(x - r_x, x + r_x)$, we have $f = g_x$. Now take a countable subcover $((x_n - r_{x_n}, x_n + r_{x_n}))_n$ of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Ah! I finally get it :) Thank you! Feel free to post your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hypothesis, for every $x\in (0, 1)$ we find Borel measurable function $g_{x}$ and $r_x>0$ such that $f=g_{x}$ on the open interval $(x-r_x, x+r_x)\subset (0, 1)$. This gives an open cover of $(0, 1)$:
$$
(0, 1) = \bigcup_{x\in (0, 1)} (x-r_{x}, x+r_x)
$$
Since $(0, 1)$ is a [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) space, this open cover has a countable subcover, i.e. we can find $x_1, x_2, x_3, …$ in $(0, 1)$ such that
$$
(0, 1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_{n}-r_{x_{n}}, x+r_{x_{n}})
$$ 
Now for any $a>0$, we have that
$$
f^{-1}((a, \infty))=\{y: f(y)>a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{y: g_{x_n}(y)>a\}\cap (x_n-r_{x_{n}}, x_n+r_{x_{n}})
$$
Each $\{y: g_{x_n}(y)>a\}\cap (x_n-r_{x_{n}}, x_n+r_{x_{n}})$ is a Borel measurable set. As a *countable* union of measurable sets, $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is measurable. Thus, $f$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: A comment for those (like me) that do not know about Lindelöf spaces: in a metric space ($\mathbb R$ here), Lindelöf is the same as second countable, which the same as separable (countable dense subset).